# Why is the move ctor not called, in this std::move case?

Tags: c++

If build and run this short example

```
#include <memory> // for class template `unique_ptr`
#define LOG() std::printf("[%p] %s\n", this, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__)

class bar_t final
{
public:
    bar_t(int val) : m_val(val) { LOG(); }
    ~bar_t(void) { LOG(); }
    bar_t(bar_t&& dying) : m_val(std::move(dying.m_val)) { LOG(); }
    int get_value(void) const { return m_val; }
private:
    int m_val;
};

class foo_t final
{
public:
    foo_t(int a_val) : m_bar(a_val) { LOG(); }
    ~foo_t(void) { LOG(); }
    bar_t m_bar;
};

std::unique_ptr<foo_t> gen_foo(int val)
{
    return std::make_unique<foo_t>(val);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if 1
    bar_t&& bar = std::move(gen_foo(42)->m_bar); // Bad
//  bar_t& bar = gen_foo(42)->m_bar; // gives same result as previous line
#else
    bar_t bar(std::move(gen_foo(42)->m_bar)); // Good
#endif
    std::printf("bar.get_value() = %d\n", bar.get_value());
    return 0;
}
```

We'll have this output

```
[0x5616d6510e70] bar_t::bar_t(int)
[0x5616d6510e70] foo_t::foo_t(int)
[0x5616d6510e70] foo_t::~foo_t()
[0x5616d6510e70] bar_t::~bar_t()
bar.get_value() = 0
```

where `bar.get_value()` returns 0 instead of 42. On the other hand, if we set the `#if` criterion to 0, build and run again, we'll have

```
[0x55acef3bfe70] bar_t::bar_t(int)
[0x55acef3bfe70] foo_t::foo_t(int)
[0x7fff70612574] bar_t::bar_t(bar_t&&)
[0x55acef3bfe70] foo_t::~foo_t()
[0x55acef3bfe70] bar_t::~bar_t()
bar.get_value() = 42
[0x7fff70612574] bar_t::~bar_t()
```

where `bar.get_value()` returns 42.

The question is why `bar.get_value()` returns 0 in the first case where the `#if` criterion is 1? How do we explain it? What happened under the hood that led to 0 instead 42, even though `std::move` is called to transfer value 42? Thanks.

Comment: `gen_foo(42)` returns a temporary that only survives until the end of the full expression. It's not bound to a reference, so the lifetime is not extended. Therefore in `std::printf("bar.get_value() = %d\n", bar.get_value());`, you've got a reference to an object that is already destroyed resulting in undefined behaviour. In the second case you make a copy in the same expression and at that time the object hasn't been destroyed yet... `auto&& fooPtr = gen_foo(42); std::printf("bar.get_value() = %d\n", fooPtr->m_bar.get_value());` would extend the lifetime though...

Comment: But `std::move` is called. Doesn't it mean: it's okay to let the argument of `std::move` be invalid? Because the underlying value is transferred to the rValue reference? I thought that's how rValue references work when they are used to receive return values of functions and prolong the lifespan of the return values.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I thought `gen_foo(42)` is a rValue, but `gen_foo(42)->m_bar` is not.

Comment: @Cody Yeah never mind, that part of my comment is wrong. But the bolded part is still true: std::move does not move a value.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Why does `std::move` not move the value in this case?

Comment: @Cody Like I said, because `std::move` **never** moves values. That's not its job (despite the misleading name). It just performs a `static_cast` to `T&&`. The move is performed when you invoke a (move) constructor or assignment.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, it explains a lot. If you posted it as an answer, I'd mark it "accepted". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is widely recognised that `std::move` has a misleading name: it does not actually perform a move. Instead, it performs a cast, similar to `static_cast<T&&>`<sup>1</sup>.

To perform a move, you need to invoke a move constructor or a move assignment operator. This doesn’t happen in your `#if 1` code branch, but it *does* happen in the other branch with the explicit constructor call. Since the constructor isn’t marked `explicit`, you could also have written

```
bar_t bar = std::move(gen_foo(42)->m_bar);
```

This *looks* like the move is performed by `std::move` but what actually happens is that `bar` is initialised by calling its move constructor.

Importantly, the reason why your first code does not involve [lifetime extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) (which would make it work even without the move) is that the temporary object that would need to be bound for lifetime extension to work is the return value of `gen_foo(42)`, not `gen_foo(42)->m_bar`.

Here’s an example where lifetime extension *does* work (note that we don’t need `std::move` since `gen_foo(42)` is already an rvalue):

```
std::unique_ptr<foo_t>&& foo = gen_foo(42);  // extends the lifetime
bar_t& bar = foo->m_bar;                     // regular reference
```

And, just for completeness, the following move-constructs `foo`. Once again `std::move` is unnecessary since `gen_foo(42)` is already an rvalue:

```
std::unique_ptr<foo_t> foo = gen_foo(42);    // move construction
bar_t& bar = foo->m_bar;                     // regular reference
```

Move constructing a `std::unique_ptr` is cheap and easy, and this code shows the common usage (there isn’t really a reason to use lifetime extension with `std::unique_ptr` objects).

---

<sup>1</sup> The [actual implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) is slightly more complex.

Comment: can I `#define move make_movable`? joking apart, the name is so misleading, as you say at the beginning of your answer, and I've never read anyone saying "oh, this is a proper name": Do you know if there was a reason for c++ committee to chose this name? There must be I assume

Comment: @GianPaolo afaik this is the proposal that was about introducing move-semantics https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm. It does mention `std::move` already, maybe somewhere there is also motivation for the name

Comment: @GianPaolo I think this section brings some insight on the choice of the name https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm#Cast%20to%20rvalue. They write "Note that this amounts to a request to move, not a demand to move". So if you see a `std::move` it expresses the intend to move, but if something is actually moved is a different question